# Ошибка при выполнение теста Codeception

Tags: php, ajax, codeception

Ошибка при попытке выполнить нажатие на кнопку "в корзину" и отправки Ajax.

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///cart/add/?r=0.7953918976709247. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.x.ajaxTransport.n.send @ jquery.min.js:6x.extend.ajax @ jquery.min.js:6$addToCartFunction @ scripts.js?v=100915_2:88x.event.dispatch @ jquery.min.js:5x.event.add.v.handle @ jquery.min.js:5
WelcomeCept.fail.html:1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://mc.yandex.ru/webvisor/325470900?rn=853299477&page-url=file%3A%2F%2F%…063&browser-info=z%3A180%3Ai%3A20151007133521%3Arqnl%3A1%3Ast%3A1444214275. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Установил http-server и запустил, как указанно [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27742070/angularjs-error-cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-protocol-schemes), но не помогло.

Comment: Selenium? Странно что пытается загрузить локальный файл, а не с веб сервера.

Comment: Да, селениум 2.47.10. Он ничего с веб сервера не хочет грузить и все подключенные скрипты с локалки тянет

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как выяснилось, это ошибка была из-за того что проект на cakephp2 и данные тесты не него не возможно сделать из-за отсутствия модуля для cakephp2.x codeception

Comment: Есть селениум и модуль Db, интеграционные тесты можно написать для любого фреймворка или cms